# How to choose which method to secure a Mulesoft API?

Tags: api, security, mulesoft

We have a Mulesoft Cloudhub environment which we are planning to deploy public APIs and we also have a VPC configured where we will deploy private APIs.

I'm looking at how best to secure the APIs and seen the following approaches:

- Basic Authentication
- Client Id and secret
- OAuth
- LDAP
- SAML

My query is when should you use each one?  Are their example use cases?   E.g. OAuth seems to be more secure than basic authentication and client id and secret so why not use OAuth all the time and forget about the other two?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is geared more towards authorisation rather than just authentication.

For example OAuth 2 has many different flows geared towards different use-cases. Such as 3 legged OAuth allowing you to use an external identity provider allow users to be authorised to access your resources. In a way, you’re not performing any authentication at all.

Http basic can still have a purpose in simple scenarios MAYBE when the cost and/or effort of using something else is not worth it and it’s internal network and the OJ already have some sort of ldap or active directory type thing is use for other apps (and using SSL is very important here as basic auth credentials are plain text)

For client id and secret, although it is similar to username/password, it’s more in the semantics - you are trusting a client rather than a person with the credentials.

For example, you can use client id to authenticate actual clients like a mobile application or a web app. Client id implementation like MuleSoft’s API Manager also allow you to add policies such as rate limiting and SLA based rate limiting so you can limit specific client applications to not overload your API.

You could use it alongside OAuth. Client ID/Secret for accessing the API but OAuth for authorising the end-user .

Here is a more detailed article discussing the pros and cons of the various common api auth mechanisms and a link to choosing between the various OAuth flows for your use-case.

https://nordicapis.com/3-common-methods-api-authentication-explained/

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use